# Sharepoint Form not sending attachment to email

Tags: infopath

I hope someone can shed some light on this.

I designed a form using Infopath, published it to the Sharepoint site. In the form, I have a section where a user can attach a file. I have the form sending the submitted info via email.

However, wen the form is submitted, the only thing that is received in the email is the form data, but NOT the attachment.

I have searched everyone to try and figure out how to get the file to also be attached to the email, but no such luck.

Would appreciate any thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the "submit as email" rule inside InfoPath, you can not send attachments.
Out of the box you can't send the actual attachment via SharePoint workflows either.

If you are attaching files directly inside InfoPath as well - those attachments become part of the infopath form, so they can't be easily accessed.  You may want to look at embedding a link into the form that allows you to open the upload form to a document library. You can then either add the document library as a data source so you can access the link value, or use a SharePoint workflow to create an email form data with document link.

If you deploy a workflow from a solution (ala Visual Studio) I do believe you could then craft it so you could access and send the actual document.