# People Picker and Attachments not showing in submit to email

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, email, people-picker, submit

In my Sharepoint online I have created a modern page. In a list I have an info path form that submits data to email all the fields show in the email expect my people picker fields and my attachment field how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is the expected behavior. InfoPath forms sent via emails carry the attachment as part of the form instead of actual attachments and make the files not available. Provide a similar post here: [Sharepoint Form not sending attachment to email.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123373/sharepoint-form-not-sending-attachment-to-email)

Consider using Microsoft Flow to send list data along with attachment as InfoPath is in the process of deprecation.
See a workable reference here: [How To Send Listitem Attachments As Email Attachment From Flow.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-listitem-attachments-as-email-attachment-from-flow/)